# passing member-function as argument to function-template

Tags: c++, templates, functor, pointer-to-member, template-function

Consider three ways to implement a routine in c++: through functors, member functions, and non-member functions. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class FOO
{
public:
  void operator() (string word)         // first: functor
  {
    cout << word << endl;
  }

  void m_function(string word)          // second: member-function
  {
    cout << word << endl;
  }
} FUNCTOR;


void function(string word)              // third: non-member function
{
  cout << word << endl;
}
```

Now consider a template-function to call the three functions above:

```
template<class T>
void eval(T fun)
{
  fun("Using an external function");
}
```

**What is the proper way to call `FOO::m_function` through eval?**
I tried:

```
FUNCTOR("Normal call");               // OK: call to ‘void FOO::operator()(string)‘
eval(FUNCTOR);                        // OK: instantiation of ‘void eval(T) [with T = FOO]’

function("Normal call");              // OK: call to ‘void function(string)’
eval(function);                       // OK: instantiation of ‘void eval(T) [with T = void (*)(string)]’

FUNCTOR.m_function("Normal call");    // OK: call to member-function ‘FOO::m_function(string)’
eval(FUNCTOR.m_function);             // ERROR: cannot convert ‘FOO::m_function’ from type
                                      //        ‘void (FOO::)(std::string) {aka void (FOO::)(string)}’
                                      //        to type ‘void (FOO::*)(std::basic_string<char>)’
                                      // In instantiation of ‘void eval(T) [with T = void (FOO::*)(string)]’:
                                      // ERROR: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘fun (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* fun) (...)’
```

Comment: `ERROR: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function `  Does that line in the error message give a hint?

Comment: I tried `eval(T fun, O object){ object.*fun("...") }` with no results

Comment: Use `(object.*fun)("...")` instead

Comment: Use `eval(T fun, O&& object)` to avoid copying your object each time you call eval.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pointer to member function and a pointer to function are two different beasts. The former takes an implicit first argument, the `this` pointer, or in other words, a pointer to the instance on which the member function is to be invoked on.

Typically, in order to be able to pass the member function as a callable object, you [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the instance on which it is to be invoked on, and then use [`placeholders`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to indicate arguments that will be passed to the callable later. In your case

```
eval(std::bind(&FOO::m_function, &FUNCTOR, std::placeholders::_1));
```

The first argument to `bind` above is the pointer to member function that you want to invoke, and the second is a pointer to the `FOO` instance on which you want to invoke `m_function`. The last one is a placeholder that indicates the first argument passed to the callable created by `bind` should be used when calling the member function.

Another way to do this is to pass a lambda expression to `eval` that takes a `char const *` (or `std::string const&`) argument and calls the member function.

```
eval([](char const *c) { FUNCTOR.m_function(c); });
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4a99cf0817db8d5)

Comment: What about declaring `m_function` as `static`? Then I can call it as `eval(FUNCTOR.m_function)`. Should I avoid this?

Comment: @vsoftco Oh, never mind. The problem is that we *do* want to bind something and `mem_fn` lacks the needed functionality.

Comment: @vagoberto If `m_function` is guaranteed not to use the state of `FOO`, then it *should* be declared `static`, and the problem does go away. Always think twice before creating a class with no state: unless there's metaprogramming involved, perhaps you really want a namespace instead.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `eval`, you cannot call a member function because you don't have any object;

you may go for this:

```
template<class T, class U>
void eval(T&& object, U fun)
{
    (object.*fun)("Using an external function");
}
```

and then

```
eval(FUNCTOR, &FOO::m_function);
```

Comment: Good approach, but I have another function similar to `eval` which I cannot edit :(