# Parameterizing a function using a struct

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameterization

The code below does not compile. The function `foo` takes a function pointer `f` as an argument, and `f` strictly takes one int as argument and returns an int. In this example, `foo` always invokes `f` with the argument `3`.  I would like to pass a function to `foo` so that when `f(3)` is evaluated, it's evaluated in conjunction with some other parameter; however, I can't pass a function with 2 ints as arguments to `foo` (this problem is an analogy for a real problem).

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int(*f)(int))
{
  std::cout << f(3) << std::endl;
}

struct plusX
{
  plusX(int x_) : x(x_) {}
  int x;
  int plus(int y)
  {
    return x + y;
  }
};

int main()
{
  plusX px4(4);
  foo(&px4.plus);  // ERROR!
}
```

> ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form
>   a pointer to member function.  Say '&plusX::plus'

Comment: C and C++ are totally different my dear friend. use one of the tag

Comment: Look up "pointer to member function". It's not the same as a regular function pointer. Ground well covered in the past; cba to find the dupe(s).

Comment: what is 'a' in your code?  Is that supposed to be 'foo'?

Comment: @AgrimPathak it's not about the std::cout, it's the fact that member functions inside structs don't exist in C, which is the fundamental issue you're asking about.

Comment: "despite the std::out"?  What about the fundamental problem that a pointer to a member function is different than a plain old function pointer - that's what really makes this not a C question.

Comment: `int(*f)(int)` can only point to a non-member function.  Possible solutions are (a) point it to a non-member function, (b) use a pointer-to-member and a pointer-to-object, (c) use `std::function`. The latter is easiest

Comment: @codesniffer Yes sorry, a is foo (edited now).  Wanted to give it a better name.

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30609314/2174266)

Comment: @Porges I don't agree that my question is a dupe to the question you posted.  Did you understand the question? I'm still trying to figure this out, and it would've been nice seeing full answers with code.  I believe the solution is more along the lines of std::function and std::bind, but still trying to arrive at a solution.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the proposed question [C++, function pointer to member function] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/c-function-pointer-to-member-function).  That question is specifically looking for a **member** function pointer to reference another **member** function.  So the answer there is different because there's no need to explicitly handle the "this" ptr along w/ the function pointer.  This question is about calling a member function from a non-member function.

Comment: (I'd have submitted this as a possible answer if this question weren't already closed as a duplicate).  There are other ways to solve this depending on what your requirements are on modifying the code (ie. are you allowed to change foo or plusX?).  A couple other ways to enable this is to make foo a template function and then either have it call the 'plus' method on the object passed to it, or--if C++11 is allowed--via a lambda at the call site.

Comment: @codesniffer Thanks for understanding this isn't a dupe!!  Unfortunately, so many questions hastily get marked as a dupe without voters having a clue of what's being asked (//end rant).  I'd love to read your answer.  Yes, plusX and foo can be modified and this is C++11.  Is there anyway this can be reopened?

Comment: I don't know what's involved in getting this question re-opened to accept answers.  My guess is that one or more of @Porges, TheDark, godel9, Smac89, m.s. needs to change their mark.  I've put my suggestions at (https://codesniffer.com/scratch/stackoverflow/parameterizing-a-function-using-a-struct/main.cpp) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions.  The first solution doesn't require refactoring code if existing code uses functions.

1) Using functors:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
void foo(F&& f)
{
  std::cout << f(3) << std::endl;
}

struct my_functor
{
  my_functor(int x_) : x(x_) {}
  int operator()(int y)
  {
    return x + y;
  }
  int x;
};

int main()
{
  my_functor f(4);
  foo(f);
}
```

2) Using std::function and std::bind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(const std::function<int(int)>& f)
{
  std::cout << f(3) << std::endl;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

int main()
{
  std::function<int(int)> f_binded = std::bind(add, 4, std::placeholders::_1);
  foo(f_binded);
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: I added some more info.  How is the answer incomplete?

Comment: Well, at first it seemed unclear to me why you'd answer your own question instead of editting it. Until I realized, you kinda answering two problem from your question. IMO the question is not clear at first and the answer is not explaining why these are valid solution. Sorry

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "two problems".  It's 1 problem, but I provided two different ways of solving it, the first one being better.